# Интересные ресурсы для программиста

Tags: книги

Привет всем. Я тут задался мыслью, что каждый день я читаю хабр, и по большому счету больше ничего. В основном статьи связанные с программированием. Пытался искать что-нибудь подобное (интересное и актуальное), но поиск не дал должных результатов. Есть еще несколько ресурса довольно не плохих: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/ - но из программирования там только js, http://net.tutsplus.com/ - здесь более разнообразно. Ну и http://www.html5rocks.com например, но и он тоже в основном js. 
Так что же я всё таки хочу спросить у вас: быть может вы раскроете мне глаза - от куда  черпать интересную информацию, а было бы прекрасно если бы вы поделились rss лентами в вашем ридере. Думаю не мне одному будет интересно узнать о полезных ресурсах. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Почему никто не упомянул google.com?

Comment: Кстати, подвопросик: есть аналоги хабра в загуборье? Ну чтоб статьи писал народ, и тематика была общая

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Скорее не для общения, а для самообразования могут пригодиться. 
[Институт инженеров электротехники и электроники (IEEE)](http://www.ieee.org)
[Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/)
[Интуит](http://www.intuit.ru/)

Comment: Интуит не очень. Видел в курсе по жс ошибку.

Comment: Касательно онлайн обучение - есть отличная статья, где описаны 27 ресурсов: http://habrahabr.ru/post/156241/ :) Спасибо за ответ !

Comment: И Вам спасибо за статью. =)

Comment: Вышла вторая часть ! http://habrahabr.ru/post/142449/

Answer (score 9):

По большому счету, Хабр в русскоязычном сегменте интернета такой один. Есть ряд других ресурсов IT-направленности, в том числе и связанных с программированием, но они куда менее популярны, посещаемы и интересны широкой аудитории. Из того, что время от времени читаю, я бы отметил следующие:

1. [RSDN.RU](http://RSDN.ru) - в общем-то весьма известный в узких кругах ресурс, на котором много всяческой информации. Между прочим, люто ненавидим на [Лурке](http://lurkmore.to/RSDN)
2. [MSDN-Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/default.aspx) - онлайн-журнал от Microsoft. Ну это если интересуетесь их продуктами и средствами разработки
3. [gotdotnet.ru](http://gotdotnet.ru/) - тоже неплохой ресурс, правда опять по продуктам Microsoft, и, честно говоря, не особо информативный. Но бывают весьма недурственные статьи
4. [TechDays.ru](http://www.techdays.ru/) - снова от корпорации зла, уже в видеоформате
5. [quizful.net](http://quizful.net) - широкий набор тестов по программированию, ну и статьи тоже есть

Из того, чем не пользуюсь, но тоже на слуху:

1. [sql.ru](http://sql.ru) - несмотря на название, далеко не только про SQL
2. [Хакер](http://xakep.ru/) - правда, тут по программированию вы вряд ли что-то найдете, да и вообще, написал скорее до кучи
3. [cyberforum.ru](http://www.cyberforum.ru/) - вообще не помню что, просто всплыло в памяти

Ну и еще, совсем напоследок:

1. [govnokod.ru](http://govnokod.ru) - - статей, тут, разумеется, нет, но бывает полезно не наступать на чужие грабли или хотя бы просто найти что-то прикольное
2. [как бы анти-Говнокод](http://doyouknowthat.ru/) - про этот ресурс я читал месяца полтора назад на Хабре, может, из него вырастет что-то полезное

Comment: http://www.opennet.ru/

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month

Comment: Гигантское спасибо за ссылку на http://doyouknowthat.ru/ :) я видел на хабре как то статью про этот ресурс, но потом случайным образом потерял ссылку, и до сих пор не мог вспомнить, как же он называется :) Еще какой то подобный ресурс есть, и я опять же не помню как он называется..

Answer (score 7):

Мой список с легким уклоном в Java.

Чтиво:

- [InfoQ](http://www.infoq.com)
- [DZone](http://www.dzone.com)
- [The Server Side](http://www.theserverside.com)
- [Lambda the Ultimate](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/)
- и новости от [The Register](http://www.theregister.co.uk) (так, для кругозора)

Болтовня:

- Разбор полетов
- [The Art Of Programming](http://taop.rpod.ru/)
- Первые выпуски месяца от [Радио-T](http://www.radio-t.com/)
- [The Scala Types](http://scalatypes.com/)

Еще много интересных ссылок приходит из Twitter-ленты (если подписываться на стоящих людей).

**UPD**. Чуть не забыл хардкорный академический [ACM Queue](http://queue.acm.org/)

Comment: за Радио-Т +1
P.S. если уж с уклоном на Java, то Вы забыли [http://javatalks.ru/][1]


  [1]: http://javatalks.ru/

Comment: @Nofate ♦ Спасибо!

Answer (score 7):

Список полезных ссылок для:

##### Backend Development

https://gist.github.com/dypsilon/5819528

##### Frontend Development

https://gist.github.com/dypsilon/5819504

##### Азбука WEB-разработчика

http://habrahabr.ru/post/69726/

Answer (score 5):

[DOU.ua](http://dou.ua/) не могу не отметить!

Comment: Зарплаты, вакансии, обсуждение каких-то мелких плюшек вроде парковки и качества печенек в офисе. И сообщество совершенно неадекватное, все разговоры сводятся к деньгам и бонусам.

Answer (score 4):

Касаемо C/C++ очень часто выручает этот сайт

[Онлайн справочник программиста на C и C++](http://c-cpp.ru/)

Ну и естественно любимый форум

[Форум программистов](http://www.programmersforum.ru/)

Answer (score 3):

Когда-то с большим удовольствием читал статьи Joel@Software: http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/Russian (переведены, возможно, не все). Других таких же качественных и легко читаемых статей так и не нашёл

Comment: Замечательные статьи.

Answer (score 3):

Читаю в твиттере разработчиков js, ретвитят и постят актуальное :)

Comment: Какой у вас тви акк? Пофолловлю тех, кого вы фолловите

Comment: Да-да-да, и нам дайте зафоловить !